# What's an efficient way to stack a multi-level pivot table in Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Given the following dataframe:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02'], 'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'C': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff'], 'val': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]})
test_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['date'])
```

I form the following pivot table (The reason for doing so is beyond the scope of this question.):

```
test_pivot_table = test_df.pivot_table(index='date', columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], values='val')
```

Suppose after I perform some operations - such as resampling the datetime index - I want it back in its original tabular form.  What's the most efficient way of transforming it back?

The current way I'm doing it right now is:

```
test_pivot_table.stack().stack().stack().to_frame('val').reset_index()
```

However, for larger dataframes, the triple `stack()` operations are slow and very memory-intensive.

Comment: `test_pivot_table.unstack().reset_index()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with removing missing values:

```
print (test_pivot_table.unstack().dropna().reset_index(name='val'))
   A  B   C       date    val
0  1  a  aa 2020-01-01  100.0
1  2  b  bb 2020-01-01  200.0
2  3  c  cc 2020-01-01  300.0
3  4  d  dd 2020-01-02  400.0
4  5  e  ee 2020-01-02  500.0
5  6  f  ff 2020-01-02  600.0
```